# How to create std::tie from std::vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, stdvector, stdtuple

Is there a way to create a `std::tie` from an `std::vector`'s elements?

Or

In other words, dynamically create a `std::tie` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the element count you want to tie at compile time, you can write a `tie_elements` function template to do this.

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t Count, typename Container>
auto tie_elements(Container&& container, std::size_t const start_index = 0) {
    return [&container, start_index]
        <std::size_t ... I>(std::index_sequence<I ...>){
            return std::forward_as_tuple(container[start_index + I] ...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<Count>());
}


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<int> const& data){
    if(data.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << data[0];
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << ", " << data[i];
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data{2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
    print(data);
    tie_elements<3>(data, 1) = std::forward_as_tuple(9, 1, 0);
    print(data);
}
```

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11
2, 9, 1, 0, 11
```

If you just want to assign a dynamic length sequence to a `std::vector` you can use `std::copy`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<int> const& data){
    if(data.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << data[0];
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << ", " << data[i];
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data{2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
    print(data);

    std::vector<int> source{9, 1, 0};
    std::ranges::copy(source, data.begin() + 1); // C++20
    // C++17: std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), data.begin() + 1);
    print(data);

    std::ranges::copy(std::initializer_list{8, 6, 4}, data.begin() + 2); // C++20
    print(data);
}
```

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11
2, 9, 1, 0, 11
2, 9, 8, 6, 4
```